# How to target a user segment of a topic in FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created a general topic as I've read that it's the easiest way to allow users to also unsubscribe themselves from FCM through the app settings.

But I'd now like to target a specific segment of these users (ie those who are subscribed to topic "news" and haven't opened the app in X days) and in the "Compose message" screen it seems like I have to pick one or the other.

So can this be done? Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving a message from FCM requires the registration of appropriate handler for the incoming message. A reference to creating a handler in your application: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

One way out here, is to identify the low activity levels in your application and make it to subscribe to another specific topic. Then you can provide a boolean condition to target your users like:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
{
   "message":{
    "condition": "'news' in topics || 'low-activity' in topics",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Hey there!",
      "title" : "It's been a long time!",
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: I haven't been able to try this, currently busy with some other stuff, but as soon as I am able to I'll try it and accept it if it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey I recently saw Google analytics suits your use case. Please do check it out [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)